# Why is my DropDownList's SelectedItem only showing the first item in the list each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I am having a problem with an ASP.NET `DropDownList` which is populated by an XML file:

```
rblState.DataSource = dsState;
rblState.DataValueField = "abbreviation";
rblState.DataTextField = "name";
rblState.DataBind();
```

This works fine and displays all the right data however, the problem occurs when I try and retrieve the selected value from the list after a button has been clicked:

```
string state = rblState.SelectedItem.Text;
Console.WriteLine(state);
```

This always outputs only the first value within the list.

Anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: is this dropdown's `AutoPostBack` property set to true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably re-binding the `DataSource` on PostBack. Instead, do this:

```
//only bind on the first request
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    rblState.DataSource = dsState;
    rblState.DataValueField = "abbreviation";
    rblState.DataTextField = "name";
    rblState.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your populating codes in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with any variables, you should always check them before trying to call sub-properties.

Check `SelectedIndex != -1` to make sure a value was selected OR check to make sure that `SelectedItem != null`.

Make sure that you are binding your `DropDownList` only on the page's first load (as Kemal stated).

Answer (score -1):

does your control have the `runat="server"` property set? That one's bitten us all at one point or another I'm sure.

Also I beleive you have to set your `AutoPostBack="true"` so it notifies the server when you change a list item. Otherwise I beleive you have to get it client side if it's not updating the server with the newly selected option.